# resolution solution for Windows RDP?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution

I'm running a Windows 10 guest VM on my Linux host at home to be able to RDP via a VPN (I establish through MS IE)  into my Desktop computer at work.

This generally works fine only that the RDP viewer gives me scroll bars (presumably) because the resolution on my Desktop at work, is the same as the resolution I use on my home screen.

I'm in Full screen mode with my VirtualBox client but I still get two Windows title bars on top (when scrolled all the way up), one from the IE window (that displays the remote desktop) and one from the maximized Putty window on the remote machine. (I of coursecan maximize the Putty insatance to get rid of the two title bars  but that still leaves me with the scrollbars

I tried to maximize the IE window with F11 but that won't work (I even have to maximize it through the Taskmanager as the maximize button is greyed out)
Is there a way around this?

Can I either reduce the remote view by a certain percentage or maybe remove the title bar of the IE window?

**Additional info**

I don't have access to the "regular" RDP config dialog as I need to use IE to establish access through a browser plugin from F5 Networks to the VPN and then click an icon (on a web page that opens) that opens another IE Window within which the remote desktop appears, i.e. I need to be able to optimize things after the RDP connection has been established.

Comment: Who is the provider of the RDP client you're running in IE (an ActiveX control I presume?)

Comment: Yes from F5 Networks

Comment: That info belongs in your question since this behavior is likely up to that control.

Comment: Ok, I'm adding it! Thanks!

Comment: Does the HTML invoke the Remote Desktop ActiveX control using a command similar to `<OBJECT ID="MsRdpClient"`? If yes, does it include the parameters `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`? Are you in a position to modify this HTML?

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure about the `<OBJECT`tag but either way, I can't modify the HTML

Comment: You can still adjust everything on your side using a browser extension such as Greasemonkey. Have a look at the page-source to see if the `<OBJECT>` tag exists. I can help in analyzing the source if this isn't confidential.

Comment: @harrymc I can't right click in the window that opens to display the remote desktop to have a look at the source code and mind, it's in IE, I don't think there's any tools embedded that woudl allow you to debug the page otherwise....

Comment: Try typing Ctrl+U or F12.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 RDP, click on More Options (lower left) and then Display Tab, and set the remote system for a lower resolution. I do this for Servers to see the server window without scroll bars. If using IE and / or the resolution of the remote machine cannot be changed, then you will need to live with the scrollbars.  I have done this as well.

Comment: John, please see the additional info I added above

Comment: IE will not manage resolution the way you want. You need to access that machine and then change (lower) the physical resolution of the machine

Comment: I don't think I want to do that because I use that same machine to work on when I'm at the office, also

Comment: Then you will need to live with the scroll bars (which I can manage as well)

Comment: I adjusted my answer to fit IE, but I think you will need to accept the scrollbars in this situation

Comment: The OP isn't using the Windows RDP client. It's an ActiveX control in IE.

Comment: Yes, and I adjusted accordingly